# Ordering of values in HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues()

Tags: java, http, servlets

`HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues()` returns a `String[]` containing all values of a given HTTP request parameter. Does anyone know if the order of the values in this array is guaranteed by specification to by the same as the order which those values were passed through in the request?

For example, if I have the GET query string `x=1&x=2&x=3`, am I *guaranteed* to receive the `String[] {"1", "2", "3"}` when I call `getParameterValues()`? It seems to work in practice, but I can't find anything which specifies that this must be the case, so I'm reluctant to rely on it.

Comment: As HttpServletRequest is an interface, it depends on its implementation.
Although I would be surprised if there is an implementation which does not return the values in the order received.

Comment: Interface documentation *can* dictate behaviour if the designer so chooses, but in this case they haven't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The javadoc for ServletRequest ([v2.5 javadoc](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/index.html)) does not mention anything about the ordering of values for that method. As such, I wouldn't rely on the order being preserved.

---

Update: also checked the spec document for 2.5, contains the following information relating to getParameterValues(). It does not mention anything about ordering with respect to the query string, so I think the behaviour you are seeing is implementation detail, not defined as part of the interface.

> The parameters are stored as a set of
>   name-value pairs. Multiple parameter
>   values can exist for any given
>   parameter name. The following methods
>   of the ServletRequest interface are
>   available to access parameters:

- getParameter
- getParameterNames
- getParameterValues
- getParameterMap

> The
>   getParameterValues method returns an
>   array of String objects containing all
>   the parameter values associated with a
>   parameter name. The value returned
>   from the getParameter method must be
>   the first value in the array of String
>   objects returned by
>   getParameterValues. The
>   getParameterMap method returns a
>   java.util.Map of the parameter of the
>   request, which contains names as keys
>   and parameter values as map values.

For future reference, the Java Servlet specs can be downloaded from [Sun, I mean Oracle's website](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/reference/api/index.html). You can double check the specific servlet version you're interested in there.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the order of values returned by `getParamterValues(String)` and entries in `getParameterMap()` **is** guaranteed by the Servlet Specification. Here's the passage:

> Data from the query string and the
>   post body are aggregated into the
>   request parameter set. Query string
>   data is presented before post body
>   data. For example, if a request is
>   made with a query string of a=hello
>   and a post body of a=goodbye&a=world,
>   the resulting parameter set would be
>   ordered a=(hello, goodbye, world).

(This is from the "HTTP Protocol Parameters" section within "The Request" chapter of the Servlet Specifications (SRV.4.1 in version 2.4, SRV.3.1 in version 2.5).)

There *doesn't* appear to be a clean way to get the names in order (`getParameterNames()` does *not* return names in the order that the browser gave). I could, I suppose, parse the raw GET string from `getQueryString()` or parse the raw POST string from `getInputStream()`, but instead I think I will add another hidden parameter and then use `getParameterValues(String)` to get its order.

If you're curious why I want to the parameters in order, it's because I have controls that the user can rearrange using jQuery, and I want to know the order that the user has chosen:

```
<form>
  <ul id=variables>
    <li>
      <input name=hello>hello
      <input type=hidden name=variableOrder value=hello>
    <li>
      <input name=world>world
      <input type=hidden name=variableOrder value=world>
  </ul>
</form>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery('#variables').sortable().disableSelection();
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't (explicitly) say anything about the ordering within query string data or post body data, only that `post body data` should appear after `query string data`. A full guarantee is implied in the example, and the reference implementation respects the original ordering, but...

Answer (score 8):

It's indeed not explicitly definied in the Servlet spec, but at least the HTML forms spec definies it explicitly in the [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) section:

> 2.The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document.

So, that part is safe. Now the servletcontainer, most logically a decent and efficient implementation would process the HTTP input stream immediately as it comes in, so the parameters would be processed in the order as they appear in the request URI (GET) or request body (POST). Collecting them in a `String[]` is the most straightforward choice as it is also used as-is in the Servlet API, so I really don't see any reason to collect it in a `HashSet` like structure first, or do a `Collections#shuffle()` or whatever and then convert it to `String[]` afterwards.

I can at least tell from experience, Tomcat does it the right way, so all major containers/appservers which are built on top of Tomcat/Catalina (IBM Websphere, JBoss AS, Sun Glassfish, etc) will also behave so. I only don't have hands on experience with Weblogic, but I would be surprised if it processes it differently (read: less efficiently).

Only the ordering of the parameter **names** is not guaranteed, logically because it's backed by a `HashMap`.

---

Summarized: the parameters are collected in a `HashMap<String, String[]>`. The names are quaranteed not ordered due to the nature of the `HashMap`. The values (one parameter name can have multiple values, e.g. `foo=bar1&foo=bar2&foo=bar3`) are in turn however ordered due to the nature of `String[]`, although this is not explicitly specified in the Servlet API.

To be on the safe side, you'd like to use a different approach, e.g.

```
foos=3&foo[0]=bar1&foo[1]=bar2&foo[2]=bar3
```

with

```
int foos = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("foos"));
for (int i = 0; i < foos; i++) {
    int foo = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("foo[" + i + "]"));
}
```

Comment: Relying on something that is not mandated by the Servlet spec is IMHO a mistake. If you do, you just take the risk to make your application non portable. Sure, one can argue about the container implementation not being efficient but that doesn't change anything, it's the expectation that was wrong at the end (regardless of how many implementations use Tomcat).

Comment: The Servlet Spec really should enforce an order.  This would make parameters with multiple values much more useful because you could correlate related parameters from a table row for example.

Comment: Can we be confident that this won’t change for Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a problem to extract param-value map from HttpServletRequest in order in accordance with  elements on the JSP. I wrote an OrderedRequestMap that parsers an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request body.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class OrderedRequestMap extends LinkedHashMap<String,String[]> {

private final String encoding;

public OrderedRequestMap(InputStream httpBody, String encoding) throws IOException {
    this.encoding = encoding;
    fill(httpBody);
}

private void fill(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "ASCII");
    int c;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        char ch = (char)c;
        if (ch == '&') {
            put(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder(1000);
        } else {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    put(sb.toString());
}

private void put(String parameter) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String[] pair = parameter.split("=");
    if (pair.length == 0 )
        return;
    String key = URLDecoder.decode(pair[0], encoding);
    String val = EMPTY_STR;
    if (pair.length > 1)
        val = URLDecoder.decode(pair[1], encoding);
    String[] values = get(key);
    if (values == null)
        values = new String[]{val};
    else {
        values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length+1);
        values[values.length - 1] = val;
    }
    put(key, values);
}


private static final String EMPTY_STR = "";
}
```

And call it like this

```
new OrderedRequestMap(request.getInputStream(), request.getCharacterEncoding());
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on HttpServletRequest interface implementation.

Comment: Why are you repeating an already given comment/answer? Please add something new or just upvote the answer you agree with and move along :)