# HTTPServletRequest.getParameterNames() not in order as in HTML Form

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have an html form which posts data to a servlet. However the order returned in getParameterNames() isn't the same as in the HTML Form.

How do i retrieve the parameters in the same order?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4733472/3377857

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of request.getParameterNames()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733373/order-of-request-getparameternames)

Comment: Your server logic should not depend on the parameters's order. Rework it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in the request are stored in a Map. A map do not warranty the order of iteration. If you really need to get the records in a particular order I suggest to add the order in the name property something like 01_firstName 02_last name and then order the map.

Answer (score 1):

This came up as a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55576) in Apache Tomcat a little while ago. The short version of that bug report is:

- Section 17.13.3 of the HTML specification (v4.01) titled "Processing form data", clearly states that "control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document."
- The Servlet specification does defer to W3C for all HTML matters.
- Strictly, 17.13.3 applies to how the client presents the data to the server
- That said, it seems reasonable to expect Servlet containers to retain this order when presenting parameters.

This has been fixed in Tomcat 8.0.x for 8.0.0-RC4 onwards and in 7.0.x for 7.0.45 onwards.