# How to get values of getParameterValues in the order they are sent?

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, getparameter

I am sending registration form data through HttpPost method to Servlet and get this data by getParameterValues.

No problem with getting data, but I get the data in random order. I want that at servlet I get the data in order of how they are sent. I try to solve this by reading in internet but nothing can help. I am posting my servlet code here.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
    String params[] = new String[7];
    int i=0;

    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println(paramName);


        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
        params[i] = paramValues[0];

        System.out.println(params[i]);

        i++;
    }
```

I get the output like this

```
5_Country
United States
4_Password
zxcbbnm
1_Lastname
xyz
0_Firstname
abc
3_Email
abc@xyz.com
6_Mobile
1471471471
2_Username
abcd
```

I want 0_Firstname first then 1_Lastname then 2_Username like that, because I want to insert this data in database. Here 0,1,2...I wrote just for indicate that I want value in this order.

Comment: Is parameter dynamic or they are fixed?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733373/order-of-request-getparameternames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get the parameter names in order by using `request.getParameterNames();` .

You can either use

```
String [] parameterNames =  new String[]{"param1","param2","param3"};

for(String param : parameterNames){
 System.out.println(param);
}
```

where `parameterNames`  conains sequence in which you want your parameters.
You can even configure it and read sequence from a config file.

OR

You can use

```
 request.getQueryString() to get the QueryString, while using GET Method
```

OR

You can use

```
 request.getInputStream() to get the QueryString, while using POST Method
 and parse the raw data to get the Query string.
```

After getting query string , you can split and use the way you want.

Comment: In first method of your solution how can i get the value of parameters.I can get the parameter in sequence.

Comment: @bhargav thanki Sorry by mistake i wrote `System.out.println` . What I meant was `request.getParameter(param)` .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Enumeration<String> enumParamNames = request.getParameterNames();
```

Convert `Enumeration` to `List` inorder to sort them.

```
List<String> listParamNames = Collections.list(enumParamNames);
```

The paramNames will look like this before sorting

`[5_Country, 4_Password, 1_Lastname, 0_Firstname, 2_Username, 3_Email]`

Sort the list by `Collections.sort(listParamNames);`

The sorted paramNames will look like this

`[0_Firstname, 1_Lastname, 2_Username, 3_Email, 4_Password, 5_Country]`

Now you can loop with `listParamNames` to get the associated `param value`

```
for(String paramName : listParamNames)
{
    System.out.println(paramName);
    System.out.print("\t");

    /* Instead of using getParameterValues() which will get you String array, in your case no need for that. You need only one `Value`, so you go with `getParameter` */
    System.out.print(request.getParameter(paramName));
}
```

**Output:**

`0_Firstname  -  abc`

`1_Lastname   -  xyz`

`etc....`

Comment: when I write String[] parameterNames =  request.getParameterNames(); It gives error change type of parameterNames to Enumeration<String>

Comment: @bhargavthanki Have a look at my updated answer with `Enumeration`