# What's the best approach to send collection of item from jsp to a servlet in a Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, request

My goal is to make sure the user may enter a list of item (let's say books), submit to a servlet the inserted values than insert the data in the database.

Let's say the presentation consists in an editable table with 10 empty rows and some event that make possible to add some new rows. The table has for example 3 columns "code", "title" and "author".

My first doubt is: how can I get collection of books from request? 
if any table's row is as follow

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="code" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="author" /></td>
</tr>
```

I could use `request.getParameterValues("code")` because any row has an input with name "code" and the same applies for the other columns. At the end I'll have three arrays, one with all codes, one with all titles and the last one with all authors.
But... As I read around the web it's not guaranteed the order of the values in the array, that is the first value of title[] could not match the title value of the first table row
so that I'll have a book with wrong title. Is it true? If so, how can I manage this situation?

Second: how I can manage a huge amount of data?

Let's say that the column are 100 and there's a script that fills thousands of row.
How should I manage this situation? Someone told me to save the data in a temp file on the server than read the file and save data in the datase. Is it the right approach?

Comment: "*it's not guaranteed the order of the values in the array*" - can you provide some source for that?

Comment: [from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317281/ordering-of-values-in-httpservletrequest-getparametervalues)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. But it seems that *practically* the order is preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order matters, I will suggest to append a row id to the input name when you are generating the form in the jsp instead of relying on the un-guarantee array order.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="code-1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title-1" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="author-1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="code-2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="title-2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="author-2" /></td>
</tr>
```

In your servlet when reading the data, you can do this:

```
int row = 1;
while(true) {
    String code = request.getParameter("code-" + row);
    String title = request.getParameter("title-" + row);
    String author = request.getParameter("author-" + row);
    row++;
    if (code == null && title == null && author == null) { //or modify this to whatever you need
        break;        
    }
    //your process here
}
```

For the second question, I don't see a real benefit of storing the html input form to a separate file first instead of just processing it right away. Actually, it is taking an extra IO to store it as a separate file before going into database which will be slowing thing down of course.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
I'm gonna implement this way for the time being. I had already thought of this but I hoped there was somthing more automatic like useBean.

But sure, if the application increase I ill need to use XML/Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is: XML

If i was creating and submitting a batch then an XML POST would be the way to go.

How many rows and columns realistically will your users want to enter before committing them to the db? Maybe you could submit them one at a time using an Ajax call?