# How to get the verbatim request body in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC (3.2.2) application where I need to check a cryptographic signature (delivered in a request header) of the request body, which contains data of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

My problem: Spring MVC seems to make it impossible to get the actual, unprocessed HTTP request body, and thus to check the signature.

- When I use the `@RequestBody` annotation in the request handler method, I get the contents, but the individual form fields are in random order - apparently regenerated from parsed form data.
- When I use a Parameter of type `HttpServletRequest`, its body is empty
- so are `Reader` or `InputStream` parameters.

How can I prevent or bypass this preprocessing of the request body?

Comment: You can't: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2317344/1686330

Comment: Btw: I assume that's also the reason why the amz s3 signature is build from an *ordered* List of request params.

Comment: @Dirk Lachowski: I'm perfectly willing to do my own parameter parsing after confirming the signature - but I need the raw, unprocessed request body to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am using a servlet filter as a workaround - it's first in the filter chain, reads the body contents and puts them into a request attribute, which I then retrieve in the controller.